# При запросе с get параметрами ничего не возвращает, только ошибку 404

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Работаю с `Postman`.

Я пытаюсь получить ограниченное количество постов из `БД MongoDB` через `get параметры`. 
Для пагинации.
При попытке запроса, получаю 404.

Если статично забить(смотрите фото), то все ок. В чем проблема, подскажите.

---

Не работает

```
router.get("/posts?limit=:limit", (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
    .limit(req.params.limit)
    .then(posts => {
      res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

---

Работает

```
router.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
    .limit(2)
    .then(posts => {
      res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

---

Работает

```
router.get("/posts/:limit", (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
    .limit(parseInt(req.params.limit))
    .then(posts => {
      res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

[image: без get параметров все хорошо]

[image: с get параметров все плохо]

[image: без get параметров все хорошо]

Comment: Get-параметры лежат в req.query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать примерно так:

```
router.post('/posts', function (req, res) {
    //подключение к БД
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true },  (err, client) => {
        if (err) res.json({ result: err});

        var db = client.db('someDB');
        var limit = req.query.limit;
        db.collection('Tests').find({}).limit(limit)

        res.json( { result : "ok"} );
        client.close();
    });
})
```

То есть вы дергаете некий сервис, куда передаете параметры через постман так:

http://example.com/posts?limit=4